# PVCS 6.0 Checkout with Folder Hierarchy

Tags: pvcs

We are using PVCS 6.0 in our current project . I want to checkout the complete project
along with the folder hierarchy into my working directory.

Currently if I select the project and do a checkout, it just dumps all the file into my working folder without any hierarchy. Any idea about how to go about this ? ...

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a private workspace and configure workspace settings in the properties of each subdirectories.
I remember I've read somewhere in the manual you can fix things by using "." as the location... anyhow hardcoding the path in the properties should be ok.